# Создание библиотеки. Как предоставить возможность ее использовать

Tags: java, android, библиотеки, android-library

Здравствуйте. Написал библиотеку с анимациями, своими классами, методами и т.д. Хочу её выложить на гитхаб. Что нужно сделать чтобы разработчик мог добавить её к себе в проект? Ну, тоесть добавить в `dependencies`, подключить и использовать? На данный момент она представлена в виде проекта, компилируемая в `apk`. Делаю впервые, поэтому не понимаю. Вопрос, наверное, детский :D

Comment: я так понимаю такие библиотеки в java реализуются в .jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно опубликовать библиотеку в какой-нибудь публичный репозиторий. Посмотрите тут: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался

Comment: Кстати, на хабре есть [аналогичная статья на русском](https://habrahabr.ru/post/266801/)